# How to allocate an array of pointers to a struct

Tags: c

I am using the CvPoint2D32f struct of opencv, which is defined as

```
typedef struct CvPoint2D32f
    {
        float x; /* x-coordinate, usually zero-based */
        float y; /* y-coordinate, usually zero-based */
    }
    CvPoint2D32f;
```

I am trying to allocate an array of pointers of these objects as follows, and it is not working.  How is this to be accomplished?

```
CvPoint2D32f *cvpoints[8];
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            (*cvpoints)[i/2].x = float(points[i]); // points is an array of ints.  
        }
        else
        {
            (*cvpoints)[i/2].y = float(points[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array of pointers to `CvPoint2D32f`, not an array of the structs themselves. You have no memory allocated for the actual structures. You have three options:

- Change your declaration to `CvPoint2D32f cvpoints[8];` so you have all of the structures in an array on the stack.
- After you allocate the array for the pointers, add a malloc statement to allocate memory. Example:

  ```
  CvPoint2D32f *cvpoints[8];
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      {
      cvpoints[i] = (CvPoint2D32f *)malloc(sizeof(CvPoint2D32f));
      }
  ```
- Use `malloc` to allocate size for all the structures. Example:

  ```
  CvPoint2D32f *cvpoints = (CvPoint2D32f *)malloc( 8 * sizeof(CvPoint2D32f));
  ```

Comment: This make sense!  But I get the error error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘CvPoint2D32f*’

Comment: Note, however, that in C you should not need to cast the return of malloc to the type of pointer. Often times when you need to it is because you are compiling with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Gavin - Huh? `malloc()` returns a `void*`. You always need to cast it. That is exactly what his error is telling him.

Comment: @Brian - yes it returns a `void*`, but I am pretty sure according to the C spec, pointers (except function pointers) can be implicitly converted without issue. It is in c++ where you can go from a pointer to a `void*` implicitly, but must explicitly cast the other way. His error is indicating that which makes me think it is a c++ compiler.

Comment: @Brian: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)#C_and_C.2B.2B - you only have to explicitly cast in C if dereferencing inline.

Answer (score 1):

```
CvPoint2D32f *cvpoints = (CvPoint2D32f*) malloc(sizeof(struct CvPoint2D32f) * 8);
memset(cvpoints, \0, sizeof(struct CvPoint2D32f) * 8);

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        cvpoints[i/2].x = float(points[i]); // points is an array of ints.  
    }
    else
    {
        cvpoints[i/2].y = float(points[i]);
    }
}
```

And when you're done with them, you free the memory:

```
free(cvpoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do these pointers point to? I guess what you want to do is allocate dynamic memory for the structs, but I don't see any memory allocation in your code. Currently all pointers point to undefined memory, so of course this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are just creating the pointers, but you need them to point to something in memory!

Example:

```
struct CvPoint2D32f *cvpoint = (struct CvPoint2D32f *)malloc(sizeof(struct CvPoint2D32f));
if (cvpoint == NULL) {
    //malloc error
}
```